# Crash on "message sent to deallocated instance 0x606 ..."

Tags: ios4, uifont

I have the following crash in my iOS app:

*** -[GSFont retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x606c7c0

A little bit of experimentation showed me that this crash happens with some choices of fonts and not with others.

I do not understand why and moreover it is difficult to know where the crash actually happens. I have set all the flags that I know of in XCode in order to debug this, but with no success.
I also tried "backtrace" and "display info" but both with no real success as one can see below:

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x0149d057 in ___forwarding___ ()
#1  0x0149cf22 in __forwarding_prep_0___ ()
#2  0x00481ec7 in -[UILabel font] ()
#3  0x00483eec in -[UILabel _drawTextInRect:baselineCalculationOnly:] ()
#4  0x00481b40 in -[UILabel drawTextInRect:] ()
#5  0x0039b6eb in -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] ()
#6  0x022069e9 in -[CALayer drawInContext:] ()
#7  0x022065ef in backing_callback ()
#8  0x02205dea in CABackingStoreUpdate ()
#9  0x02205134 in -[CALayer _display] ()
#10 0x02204be4 in CALayerDisplayIfNeeded ()
#11 0x021f738b in CA::Context::commit_transaction ()
#12 0x021f70d0 in CA::Transaction::commit ()
#13 0x022277d5 in CA::Transaction::observer_callback ()
#14 0x0150cfbb in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#15 0x014a20e7 in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#16 0x0146abd7 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#17 0x0146a240 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#18 0x0146a161 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#19 0x01e60268 in GSEventRunModal ()
#20 0x01e6032d in GSEventRun ()
#21 0x0037242e in UIApplicationMain ()
#22 0x00001c62 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbfffef28) at /Users/.…../main.m:14
(gdb) display info 0x606c7c0
No symbol "info" in current context.
(gdb)
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have just experienced this. In my case it had to do with UITextView. I found you cannot set the text before setting the font or you get the "-[GSFont retain]: message sent to deallocated instance..." crash. This applies to UITextViews you manually create or that are created via a xib file. If you do use a UITextView in a xib file make sure you delete all the default text in the xib file for the text view because ios seems to set the text before the font when defined in a xib file.

Update.. also just ran across an incident in which a UILabel in a xib file was causing the same problem - even without default text. Not exactly sure what the problem with UILabels is but after removing the UILabels, the crash disappeared. Added the labels back a few at a time and the crash stayed away (go figure).

Hope this helps.